Using Sinus or Cosinus theorem gives an other result. What's wrong?
Suppose we are in the following situation :

So $AB= 10$ cm and $BC=5$ cm, and $\beta =43$ degree. So using Cosinus theorem, I get $$AC= \sqrt{AB^2+BC^2-2AB\cdot BC\cdot \cos(\beta )}=7,20\ cm$$
Now for $\gamma $, using Sinus theorem I get
$$\gamma =\arcsin\left(\frac{AB\cdot \sin(\beta )}{AC}\right)=71,26\ \text{degree}.$$
However, using Cosinus theorem, I get
$$\arccos\left(\frac{AC^2+BC^2-AB^2}{2\cdot AC\cdot BC}\right)=108,74 \ \text{degree}.$$
Why do I get two different answer ? What's wrong in my solution ?

$180-108.74=71.26$.

The equation $\sin\theta=(\cdots)$ in these situations generally has two supplementary solutions for $\theta$ in the interval $[0^\circ,180^\circ]$, but the $\arcsin$ function is typically chosen to have range $(-90^\circ,90^\circ)$. Thus, when the solution $\theta$ is outside of $\arcsin$'s range, you need to take the supplementary angle, i.e. $180^\circ-\arcsin$, to get the true $\theta$ which matches the triangle. This is necessary when using the Law of Sines, but not the Law of Cosines (the cosine function doesn't have this issue).

Because $\sin\gamma =u$ implies $\gamma=\arcsin u$ only if $\gamma$ is on the properly defined branch of the inverse sine function, meaning an acute angle or, at the extreme, a right angle if the sine equals $1$. Here $\gamma$ is obtuse, so we are not on the right branch for the inverse sine to work.
On the other hand, all angles from $0°$ to $180°$ are on the right branch for $\arccos$ to work. So the inverse cosine calculation always gives a right answer once you know the side lengths, which in this case is your $108.74°$. It's a significant advantage of the cosine law versus the sine law.
It is good practice to figure all the angles of a triangle and check that their sum is 180°. If you use the sine law to figure $\alpha$ as well as $\gamma$, you find that $\alpha\approx28.26°$. This together with the $71.26°$ obtained from the inverse sine function at $C$ and $\beta=43°$ does not give a sum of $180°$. Instead the largest result is the sum of the other two angles and thus must represent an exterior angle at $C$. So to get the interior angle for $\gamma$ we would take the supplement, thus $\gamma=(180-71.26)°=108.74°$, and then the angle sum checks out.

Using Trig Sine Rule you got the result for $\gamma$ angle to be acute rather than obtuse as sketched.
The inverse arcsine function admits two (plus many concyclic) solution values ( one in quadrant 1 and other in quadrant2) as
$$ (\theta, 180^{\circ}-\theta )$$
and you missed the second one.
